# how to pass array of chrono::DateTime<Utc> to postgres in rust?

Tags: postgresql, rust

I have code that is attempting to pass an array of chrono::DateTime values to a stored procedure in postgres.

```
let stmt = connection.prepare_cached("call proc($1)").await.unwrap();
if let Ok(_) = connection.execute(&stmt, &[&array]).await {
    info!("worked");
} else {
    error!("error");
}
```

but I am getting this error:

```
[Error { kind: ToSql(2), cause: Some(WrongType { postgres: TimestampArray, rust: "&[chrono::datetime::DateTime<chrono::offset::utc::Utc>]" }) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error, it's probably a mismatch between the Rust type and the PostgreSQL type when attempting to pass an array of [chrono::DateTime](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.DateTime.html) values to a stored procedure.

You can try converting it before passing it

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use postgres_types::ToSql;

// Convert the array of `chrono::DateTime` values
let converted_dt: Vec<_> = date_array.iter().map(|dt| dt.naive_utc()).collect();

// Or try this:
// let converted_dt: Vec<String> = date_array.iter().map(|dt| dt.to_rfc3339()).collect();


let stmt = connection.prepare_cached("call proc($1)").await.unwrap();
if let Ok(_) = connection.execute(&stmt, &[&naive_datetimes]).await {
    info!("worked");
} else {
    error!("error");
}
```

Comment: this worked. thanks. changing from chrono::DateTime to NaiveDateTime worked.